# Realistic dice throwing animation with predefined outcome

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, algorithm, 3d, physics

I need to create a small dice game in Flash. The random number generator is external and I have to create a 3D realistic dice animation with that outcome.

I'm using Away3D engine and JigLib for physics.
So far the best idea I've had is to do many simulations and create a list of outcomes and their corresponding input parameters (initial position, initial orientation and the forces added to the RigidBody).

This is not working so well. Sometimes for the same parameters the outcome is different.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you seeding the external RNG the same way every time?

Comment: I have no control over the RNG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the right thing to do is have a library of pre-defined courses (calculated in advance), knowing which side of the dice *will* be on top.  Then just re-map the sides of the dice, so it starts out in the right position - and ends with the right face up.

Comment: Why calculate the courses in advance? If you have the computing power you can calculate a brand new course, then remap the faces, then display animation of the throw. The results will be correct, and every throw will look different.

Comment: computingPower != flashPlayer : )

Comment: Beta is right. I'm making a new animation for every throw and "save" it by copying the RigidBody's position and orientation every frame. Then I just remap the faces and replicate that exact course. Thanks for the answers.